# Test lync presence without having lync installed

Tags: 2013, presence-indication

I've created a content search web part that use lync presence. Is there a way to test lync presence ( away, offline, online.. ) on specific users without having lync installed in the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per below KB article MSFT says...when the Lync client is not installed or when the Lync user is not signed in then Presence will not available.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2813701/en-us

Same from another post:
[Presence indicators without Lync](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15446/presence-indicators-without-lync)